# Extracting from a list in haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I'm pretty new to Haskell and don't fully understand the Maybe monads.

```
data Hmm = Hmm [Maybe Int]
 deriving (Show, Eq)

yd = Hmm [Just 8, Just 5,Nothing,Just 2, Nothing, Just 2, Nothing,Nothing]

getVal = case yd of
  [Just val] -> putStr val
  [Nothing] -> putStr "."
```

I want to extract my list by replacing Nothing with a dot and Just n with n (all in one line). However, this code gives me an error.

```
Couldn't match expected type "Hmm" with actual type '[Maybe a0]'

In the pattern : [Nothing] 
In a case alternative: [Nothing] -> putStr "."
In the expression:
  case yd of
  [Just val] -> putStr val
  [Nothing] -> putStr "."
```

basically i want the list above to be in the format " 85.2.2.. "

Comment: Well, what error?

Comment: And, for that matter, what code?

Comment: You should always include the error in your question if you get one.

Comment: Do you want to *replace* Nothing with a "." or do you want to *print* a "."? Your code and your description of your code say two different things.

Comment: yes, replace Nothing with a "."

Comment: Then why are you using `putStr`?

Comment: The compiler tells you exactly what's wrong. `yd` has type `Hmm` but the pattern `[Nothing]` only matches on types `[Maybe a]` for any type `a`. In order to pattern match on an expression `yd :: Hmm` you have to pattern match on the `Hmm` constructor. (NB: this has nothing to do with monads).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you the error:

> Couldn't match expected type "Hmm" with actual type '[Maybe a0]'

Let's simplify by using `[Int]` instead of `[Maybe Int]` so we can take monads completely out of the picture here. Let's re-write your test cases by using `0` instead of `Nothing`, and `x` instead of `Just x`

```
data Hmm = Hmm [Int]
 deriving (Show, Eq)

yd = Hmm [8, 5, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0]

getVal = case yd of
  [0] -> putStr "."
  [x] -> putStr $ show x
-- N.B. I had to reverse the order here since `[x]` will match before `[0]`.
-- This isn't an issue when you're still using Maybes, since Just x doesn't match Nothing
```

Now we've got no monadic elements at all (except `getVal :: Hmm -> IO ()`, but...) and you'll still have the same issue as before. `yd` is constructed as a `Hmm`, but the only pattern matching you're doing on it is looking for an `[a]`. In addition, both patterns are only looking for single-element lists, so they wouldn't match even if `yd :: [Int]`.

Let's re-write using the `Hmm` constructor in our pattern match and recursing correctly to capture the whole list. We'll also re-write `getVal` to return the `String` so we don't even have to mess with the `IO` monad that `putStr :: String -> IO ()` returns.

```
import Data.Char (intToDigit)

data Hmm = Hmm [Int]
  deriving (Show, Eq)

yd = Hmm [8, 5, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0]

getVal :: Hmm -> String
getVal (Hmm [])    = []
getVal (Hmm (0:xs) = '.'          : getVal (Hmm xs)
getVal (Hmm (x:xs) = intToDigit x : getVal (Hmm xs)

result :: String
result = getVal yd
```

Notice how I include three alternations in my pattern matches. One for `Hmm []` -- an empty list wrapped in a `Hmm` type, one for `Hmm (0:xs)` -- a non-empty list wrapped by a `Hmm` whose first value is zero, and one for `Hmm (x:xs)` -- a non-empty list wrapped by a `Hmm`, and each result but the first is recursive. This will return:

```
getVal yd =
getVal (Hmm (8:[5, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0])) =
'8' : getVal (Hmm (5: [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0])) =
'8':'5' : getVal (Hmm (0: [2, 0, 2, 0, 0])) =
'8':'5':'.' : getVal (Hmm (2: [0, 2, 0, 0])) =
'8':'5':'.':'2' : getVal (Hmm (0: [2, 0, 0])) =
'8':'5':'.':'2':'.' : getVal (Hmm (2: [0, 0])) =
'8':'5':'.':'2':'.':'2' : getVal (Hmm (0: [0])) =
'8':'5':'.':'2':'.':'2':'.' : getVal (Hmm (0:[])) =
'8':'5':'.':'2':'.':'2':'.':'.': getVal (Hmm []) =   -- base case!
'8':'5':'.':'2':'.':'2':'.':'.':[] =      -- re-write as list
['8', '5', '.', '2', '.', '2', '.', '.']  -- re-write as String
"85.2.2.."
```

Do note that this is just:

```
toString :: Hmm -> String
toString (Hmm xs) = map f xs where
  f 0 = '.'
  f x = intToDigit x
```

To use a `Maybe Int` here and return this to the world of monads, just apply the same changes to your code

```
import Data.Char (intToDigit)

data Hmm = Hmm [Maybe Int]
  deriving (Show, Eq)

yd = Hmm [Just 8, Just 5, Nothing, Just 2, Nothing, Just 2, Nothing, Nothing]

getVal :: Hmm -> String
getVal (Hmm []) = []
getVal (Hmm (Nothing:xs)) = '.'          : getVal (Hmm xs)
getVal (Hmm (Just x :xs)) = intToDigit x : getVal (Hmm xs)

-- or equivalently

getVal' :: Hmm -> String
getVal' (Hmm xs) = map f xs where
  f Nothing = '.'
  f (Just x) = intToDigit x
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation + time. could you please explain the last bit (map f) as it seems to be a nice elegant approach

Comment: what about `Just 17` though? also, cf. [Data.Maybe.maybe](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:maybe)

Comment: @WillNess you could collect as a `[String]` and exit the function with `intercalate " "`, but that's ultimately a different question isn't it?

Comment: @BrandonAjax `map` has type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. You're passing a `[Maybe Int]` and want a `[Char]` back, so that's your `a` and `b`. The function `f` turns all `Nothing`s to `'.'`s, and all `Just x`s to `intToDigit x`. As WillNess pointed out, this will fail for any `x>16` (`intToDigit 17` throws an exception), but it's also unclear what the appropriate output would be in that case (how is `getVal $ Hmm [Just 17]` different from `getVal $ Hmm [Just 1, Just 7]`?)

Comment: ed. above: this will fail for any `x>=16`

Comment: @AdamSmith right, converting to `Char` was wrong. Just convert to `String`s with `map $ maybe "." show` and `concat` all the results, or `mapM_ putStr` them. No `" "` is necessary.

Comment: @WillNess right but as I mentioned in my comment above, the desired result of that implementation is ambiguous since `[Just 17]` and `[Just 1, Just 7]` would appear synonymous.